# Unresolved Error When using bitmap to shrink resolution

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to use the bitmap code given from developer.android.com @ https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. I think I almost have it but am currently getting an error when trying to find my picture when creating the image view in the java file.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ion);
    ImageView ionImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.ion2);
    ionImageView.setImageBitmap(
            decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ion2,     500, 500));
}
```

The error is in the findViewById(R.drawable.ion2). I am not sure what I am suppose to call there instead.

Answer (score 0):

it should be the `id` of ImageView in your `activity_ion.xml` layout.
for example:

```
ImageView ionImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ionTitan);
```

see the difference between `R.id` and `R.drawable`

Comment: Okay but what if ion2 is a drawable? when i change it to findViewById(R.drawable.ion2) it doesn't allow that. I realize that because it's still looking for a view. I guess I'm confused if I am suppose to pass in my entire activity, or just the image that I want to use for the bitmap

Comment: please post `activity_ion.xml` so I can see, what the id of ImageView where you want to display the drawable

Comment: `<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="175dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ion2"
            android:id="@+id/ionTitan"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>`

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure how much of the .xml you wanted. I could not post the entire thing but this is the part of interest. I can try to format it better as I did not think it would come out as it did @hakim. The picture I want to add is ion2 in drawable but it lags the app which is why I am trying to use a bit map.

Comment: @MichaelPhilipps I see, so the id of ImageView is `ionTitan`, I update my answer, please check

Comment: So there aren't any errors and it runs but it still lags so I can't tell if the bit map is working or not. Thanks for the help though